# URL::previous() devolve caminho incompleto

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-rotas

Como estou estudando o livro [Code Bright](https://leanpub.com/codebright-ptbr), de vez em quando aparece uns erros que demoro a resolver. Porém este não encontrei uma solução no Google.

Ao fazer o `Redirect::to()` de uma rota a outra deveria ser exibido o endereço completo anterior, porém aparece apenas a URL da minha `vhost` sem o restante da rota.

#### Código do livro Code Bright:

```php
Route::get('first', function()
{
    // redirect to the second route
    return Redirect::to('second');
});

Route::get('second', function()
{
    return URL::previous();
});
```

Quando entro no `endereço/first` e sou redirecionado para a rota `endereço/second`, deveria aparecer escrito `endereço/first` mas aparece apenas endereço.

## Pergunta

Qual seria a solução correta para resolver a impressão da url de retorno?

Detalhe, verifiquei no github que ao que entendi o `Redirect::to` gera uma chamada 302 que não transmite a informação de onde esta vindo a requisição da rota. Talvez esteja errado sobre isto.

Comment: Só para te informar, as tags são usadas para ajudar localizar as perguntas. Inclusive elas são usadas para ajudar a indexação no Google. É feito de um jeito bem inteligente. Portanto o nome no título não ajuda a busca, Ter um não é apenas um gosto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método **`URL::previous()`** se baseia no [**`HTTP Referer`**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) que é a grosso modo uma informação que seu navegador envia ao site que está sendo acessado no cabeçalho da requisição (**`HTTP Headers`**), informando qual a URL o usuário estava quando fez a requisição.

Esse comportamento de enviar o **`Referer`** não é homogêneo e seu navegador pode não estar enviando essa informação.

Para verificar se o cabeçalho **HTTP Referer** foi enviado ou não, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//  PHP "puro"
echo $_SERVER['REFERER'];

// Laravel
echo Request::header('referer');
```

Se o usuário mandar recarregar a página, essa informação será perdida, ela só existe se o usuário estiver acessando a página através de um **Link** (`<a />`)

A melhor prática é implementar um mecanismo que guarde a página atual em sessão, como essa:

```
// Use como filtro, antes das rotas, ou em seu controller, 
// o importante é executar o código em todas as páginas
if(Session::get('url_atual')) {
    Session::put('url_anterior', Session::get('url_atual'));
} 
Session::put('url_atual', URL::current());
```

E então, se precisar criar ou link ou fazer um redirecionamento que levem até a página anterior, basta usar:

```
Redirect::to(Session::get('url_anterior'));
```

---

> **Nota1:** o exemplo acima está porcamente implementado, use-o com cautela em um sistema em produção.

> **Nota 2:** Veja a Implementação do Método em:
>   https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php
>   linhas 72 a 82:

```
public function previous()
{
    return $this->to($this->request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas isto não resolve o problema da URL de retorno. Quando requisito a impressão da URL de onde se veio o redirecionamento não retorna o que necessito e sim apenas o domínio do site.

Além do mais a duvida não era com relação a roteamento e sim requisitar a URL de onde se veio.

No caso espero que se venho do link `https://meusite.com/first` ao fazer `URL::previous()` espero que ele me retorno este endereço com o caminho da rota.

Comment: na pergunta você indica que faz uso do Redirect::to e não URL:previous()

Comment: mas vou editar a resposta para tentar te ajudar, qual servidor web você usa? apache + php normal?

Comment: apache + php padrão.
Resposta para **$ apachect -v**: 
`erver version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul  7 2013 18:05:17`.
Resposta para **$ php -v**: `PHP 5.4.21 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2013 13:24:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans`.

Comment: @ThiagoPrado crie a seguinte rota, mostre a resultado de Request::headers(); por favor

Comment: @ThiagoPrado Troquei a resposta, veja se ajuda agora!

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho. Gostaria de pedir se possível que você demonstre a melhor forma de implementação para este caso. Como você disse que esta implementado de forma porca qual seria a melhor forma?

Comment: Sim @ThiagoPrado, tem algo semelhante vou compartilhar aqui assim que der um tempo.